# How to calculate web service client idle time

Tags: java, cxf

A apache CXF based soap web service client consumes a web service which has a heart beat service as well. If the client did not send any request to the web service for 10 seconds, the client is supposed to send a heart beat request to the server. My question is how do we calculate this idle 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

If you have single class were you are calling web service I think you can implement as below.

**KPHeartBeat.java**

```
public class KPHearBeat {

    private static Timer timer;
    static{
        timer = new Timer();
    }

    public String callWebService(int input){

        timer.cancel();
        System.out.println("calling my webService");
        startTimer();
        System.out.println("Starting timer");
        return "Done";
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        timer.purge();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                System.out.println("Calling Heart Beat service");

            }
        }, 10000, 10000);
    }

}
```

JUNIT class;

```
public class KPTestTimer {

    @Test
    public void testTimer(){

        KPHearBeat kp = new KPHearBeat();

        kp.callWebService(1);
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        kp.callWebService(2);
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(8000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        kp.callWebService(3);
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(25000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

if you have multiple methods and you are calling it over different places in the code then I think you can use singleton class which would handle timer. I don't think interceptors would really help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how you implement the client.

Here are my suggestion:

you can setup the flag to the client, if the client invoke the service it can set the flag to be true, and  you have a timer to check the flag and reset the flag every 10 seconds. Once the flag is false before the time reset it, the client can send a ping to the heart beat service.